# php array merge all elements into one and remove the quotes

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need to parse some data from a text and so i copy/pasted it into an array and used it like this:

```
   $array = array("_alpha","_beta","_gama","_delta","_epsilon");
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      {use the value in my script bellow....}
   }
```

The data was coming from a script that had private declarations on the top of the file looked like this, so it was easy to just copy/paste it.

```
$private = ["_alpha","_beta","_gama","_delta","_epsilon"];
```

Now i had to parse many files so i tried to gather that $array data as best as i could into one array, so i can parse it using the same function...Well the best i could come out with is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "_alpha","_delta","_beta","_epsilon","_delta","_kapa",
    [1] => "_beta","_alpha","_delta","_kapa","_lamda","_epsilon","_array","_alpha"
    [2] => "_epsilon","_array","_alpha","_theta","_omega"
    [3] => "_alpha"
    [4] => "_kapa","_lamda","_epsilon"
    [5] => "_beta","_epsilon","_delta","_kapa","_lamda"
    [6] => "_omega","_omega","_delta"
        ....
        ....
}
```

Each line represents the header from a file. **Note the quotes around the values**...
How can i make the above look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => _alpha
    [1] => _beta
    [2] => _gama
    [3] => _delta
    [4] => _epsilon
    ...
    ...
    ..
)
```

Each value on its own, and without the quote or commas etc....just a plain value.

I can also extract the data in this format..but i think thats harder to do:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "_alpha"
                        [1] => "_beta"
                        [2] => "_gama"
                        [3] => "_delta"
                        [4] => "_epsilon"
                        ...
                        ...
                        ..
                    )

    [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "_alpha"
                        [1] => "_beta"
                        [2] => "_gama"
                        [3] => "_delta"
                        [4] => "_epsilon"
                        [5] => "_epsilon"
                        ...
                        ..
                    )
  ...... etc etc ......
  [10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "_alpha"
                        [1] => "_delta"
                        [2] => "_omega"
                    )
}
```

_Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$private = ["_alpha","_beta","_gama","_delta","_epsilon"];
print_r($private);
Array
(
    [0] => _alpha
    [1] => _beta
    [2] => _gama
    [3] => _delta
    [4] => _epsilon
)
```

i dont know whats the problem
but when i use your codes everything works fine

Comment: uhmmm i am parsing many files and i gather all the headers in a loooong array...please read carefully. i need to make that array holding 1 value only on each cell. not 10 or 5 or 6 with double quotes in it and commas as well... what you are showing me is when i was doing it with 1 file manually...right now i am holding 100 files of arrays merged into one...but with the format it had..i need plain values one next to the other...similar to what you posted now....like a huuuuuge array.

Comment: I tried, i really did..5 hours now i've been struggling with this.
It needs a combination of regular expressions as well to remove the quotes and commas and get them all in the same array.
I just edited my first post..i can extract the data in another way as well..without the commas, but still with quotes..at least on each line.
Still though not all under the same array, next to eachother.

Comment: you can use this regex for your task  $str = '"_yada"';
preg_match('/"([\s\S]+)"/i', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
Array
(
 [0] => "_yada"
 [1] => _yada
)

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, thats the easy part :) I've been trying to join that into one for the past 5h hehehe. Thats my biggest problem really.

Comment: omg! thats it! Thank you so much...i can finally go to sleep lol.
5:26 in the morning :)
Thanks again!

Comment: no problem it was hard to understand what you want make but now we have it :)